# Join new company

Tags: career-development, colleagues

I’m a pretty junior web developer  (1,5 years experience) working for a digital studio, doing simple and a few complex web pges for a lot of clients.

I just applied to a single product company, who seems to use a lot of the latests stuff ( testing, continuous deployment) and even if they wanted a senior, still offered me a position after a code review.

I’m affraid it might be to much level for me, and I’m very happy with our current team, but I think in my current job they all are pretty lazy and dont want to do testing, etc

I’m affraid to let this chance go out and stay stucked forever and, on the other hand, leave the job and fail in the new one.

What can I do? How can I know if im fully prepared?

Comment: Right now it's not really clear what you are asking; questions here require specific goals that can be addressed. I encourage you to take a look at our [tour] and [help]. I also think that you might find this question on [Imposter Syndrome](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11765/ive-somehow-convinced-everyone-that-im-actually-good-at-this-how-to-effect) relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you've misrepresented yourself in the interview, you don't have to make the call yourself if you are prepared or not.  The real question you should be asking is **are you ready to learn?**  It's up to the hiring company to determine if you are prepared or not, and in this case, you have an offer, so apparently they think you are.  Speaking from a development experience, I would jump at a company that offered experience in the "latest" stuff, this is the kind of stuff that can set your career in motion with future advancement.